# Is $G/H$ always a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Given a normal subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$, is there always an injective homomorphism
>   $$\varphi:G/H\to G?$$
>   In other words, is $G/H$ a subgroup of $G$?

If we pick an arbitrary representative element of each coset, we can get an injective map $\varphi:G/H\to G$, but I am not sure if we can always choose the $g_i$'s to get a homomorphism.

The requirement would be that if $\{g_i\}$ is the chosen set of representatives of the cosets of $G$ by $H$, then for each $i,j$ we have that $g_ig_j$ is the chosen representative for the coset $g_ig_jH$, i.e. $g_ig_jH=g_kH$ for a unique $k$. Can we always choose some $g_i$ to satisfy that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$. The centre of $Q_8$ is $\{1, -1\}$ and $Q_8/\{1, -1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, but every order four subgroup of $Q_8$ is cyclic and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. As $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, there is no subgroup of $Q_8$ isomorphic to $Q_8/\{1, -1\}$.

Comment: I think this is the smallest counter-example. For Abelian finite groups we should always find some isomorphic subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Consider $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. That's surely no subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ because $\mathbb Z$ has only one element of finite order and $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ has 3.

Comment: Or even $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Not to speak about $\mathbb Z/115\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I forgot to specify $G$ is finite....